# Filling a dataframe from a dictionary keys and values: efficient way

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, dictionary

I have the following dataframe as an example.

```
df_test = pd.DataFrame(data=0, index=["green","yellow","red"], columns=["bear","dog","cat"])
```

I have the following dictionary with keys and values that are the same or related to the index and columns od my dataframe.

```
d = {"green":["bear","dog"], "yellow":["bear"], "red":["bear"]}
```

I filled my dataframe according with the keys and values that are presented, using:

```
for k, v in d.items():
    for x in v:
        df_test.loc[k, x] = 1
```

My problem here is that the dataframe and the dictionary I'm working with are very large and it took too much time to compute. Is there a more efficient way to do it? Maybe iterating over rows in the dataframe instead of keys and values in the dictionary?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because performance is important use [`MultiLabelBinarizer`](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.preprocessing.MultiLabelBinarizer.html):

```
d = {"green":["bear","dog"], "yellow":["bear"], "red":["bear"]}

from sklearn.preprocessing import MultiLabelBinarizer

mlb = MultiLabelBinarizer()
df = pd.DataFrame(mlb.fit_transform(list(d.values())),
                  columns=mlb.classes_,
                  index=list(d.keys()))
print (df)
        bear  dog
green      1    1
yellow     1    0
red        1    0
```

And then add missing columns and index labels by [`DataFrame.reindex`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.reindex.html):

```
df_test = df.reindex(columns=df_test.columns, index=df_test.index, fill_value=0)
print (df_test)
        bear  dog  cat
green      1    1    0
yellow     1    0    0
red        1    0    0
```

Answer (score 0):

use `get_dummies()`

```
# convert dict to a Series
s = pd.Series(d)
# explode your list into columns and get dummies
df = pd.get_dummies(s.apply(pd.Series), prefix='', prefix_sep='')

          bear    dog
green        1      1
yellow       1      0
red          1      0
```

## update

```
# convert dict to a Series
s = pd.Series(d)

# create a new data frame
df = pd.DataFrame(s.values.tolist(), index=s.index)

# get_dummies
new_df = pd.get_dummies(df, prefix='', prefix_sep='')
```

Comment: I don't know why but using your code the number of columns of my dataframe are way more than before